# Getting error when calling Stored Procedure w/ Parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, .net-4.5, sql-server-2012-express

When I try to call my stored procedure using the a entity framework context, I get the following error at run time. "The parameterized query '(@Mac nvarchar(30),@tagList [TagListType] READONLY)EXEC SaveMsg' expects the parameter '@Mac', which was not supplied."

on the line

```
var result = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)databaseAPI).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, new SqlParameter("@Mac",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30,reader.MAC),sqlParamTags);
```

Here is the rest of the relevant code.

```
DataTable dtTags = getDataTableTags(info.TagList.ToList());

//**call stored procedure

SqlParameter sqlParamTags = new SqlParameter("tagList", SqlDbType.Structured);
sqlParamTags.Value = dtTags;
sqlParamTags.TypeName = "TagListType";



string command = "EXEC " + "SaveMsgData" + " @Mac, @tagList;";

var result = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)databaseAPI).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, new SqlParameter("@Mac",SqlDbType.NVarChar,100,reader.MAC),sqlParamTags);
```

Here is my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE TYPE TagListType AS TABLE
(                     
    TagID nvarchar(100),                
    AntNum int
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SaveMsgData 
@Mac nvarchar(30),
@tagList TagListType READONLY
AS

DECLARE @ReaderID int

DECLARE @AntList TABLE (AntennaID int, AntNum int, TargetNumOfTags int)

--SELECT @ReaderID = -1

SELECT @ReaderID = Id
    FROM dbo.Readers
    WHERE MAC = @Mac

IF (@ReaderID >= 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @AntList (AntennaID,Antnum,TargetNumOfTags) 
    SELECT id, AntennaNumber, numOfTags 
    FROM Antennae
    WHERE ID = @ReaderID

    DECLARE @count int
    DECLARE @len int                    
    SET @count = 0
    SET @len = 0

    WHILE @count <= @len
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @LocalAnt int
        DECLARE @LocalTarget int
        DECLARE @LocalAntID int
        DECLARE @LocalStatus int
        DECLARE @LocalTagsRead int

        --set local variables need in loop--
        SELECT @LocalAnt = Antnum, @LocalTarget = TargetNumOfTags, @LocalAntID = AntID FROM #AntList WHERE Antnum = @count

        --Decided where reading passed or failed--
        SELECT @LocalTagsRead = COUNT(*) FROM @tagList WHERE AntNum = @count

        IF @LocalTagsRead = @LocalTarget
            BEGIN
                SET @LocalStatus = 0
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @LocalStatus = 1
            END

        --insert Tags in to tag table--
        DECLARE @ReadingID int

        INSERT INTO Readings (Status,TargetNumOfTags,numOfTagsRead, TimeStamp, Antenna_Id, Reader_Id) VALUES ( @LocalStatus, @LocalTarget, @LocalTagsRead, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @LocalAntID, @ReaderID) 

        SELECT @ReadingID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        --insert Tags in to tag table--
        INSERT INTO Tags (TagID) SELECT TagID FROM @tagList WHERE AntNum = @LocalAnt

        --insert Tags and Readings in to TagReading table--
        INSERT INTO TagReadings (Tag_Id, Reading_ID) SELECT TagID,  @ReadingID FROM @tagList WHERE AntNum = @LocalAnt 

        SET @count = @count + 1
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Check the value of `sqlParamTags` if it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SqlParameter has an overload with the signature (Name, SqlDbType, Size, Value). The overload you're using is expecting "SourceColumn" as the final parameter. So, you're creating the parameter but not specifying it's value.

You're going to need to change it to something like this:

```
new SqlParameter("@Mac", reader.MAC);
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That was it! I did that to fix another error... Lol I did this instead.

SqlParameter sqlParamMac = new SqlParameter("@Mac", reader.MAC);
                                sqlParamMac.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;

but now I am getting error that it cannot convert the nvarchar to an int, but i shouldn't be trying to do that.

Comment: What datatype is dbo.Readers.MAC?

Comment: it's a string in the context, but it's not throwing when assigning to sqlParameter. It is doing it when calling the stored procedure.

and nvarchar(MAX) in the database.

Comment: That makes sense as far as when the error is happening. If you go into SQL and run this query `SELECT Id FROM dbo.Readers WHERE MAC = 'something'` does it work?

Comment: Where I'm headed here is; it sounds like you've got an error in the stored procedure someplace where you're supplying a NVARCHAR value when the database is expecting and INT. I would check through the procedure and run each statement to find where the culprit is.

Comment: The answer to the select statement is yes it returns just fine. I'm looking thought the ST now. I'll report back when I figure it out.

Comment: You were correct it was in my stored procedure. seeeems to be working now.